# Is there a way change the colour display of the site in the browser? Replace the red with monochromatic or any other colour?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, colors, website

Are there any extensions or ways to change the output of the website colours?  i use certain websites quite often (like thesaurus) and their bright red colour increases my anxiety. I don't know how silly this sounds, but it's very hard to use it. I use chrome/win but will be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome doesn't offer a built-in method for replacing the colors of
websites, so you will need to use an extension.

Some extensions which might help (in no particular order):

- [Website Color Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/website-color-changer/oenehcifpefblopdehjemeheenoamaed?hl=en)
- [Change Colors](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/change-colors/ageghplgcapnfpdhapeemolbmfccclke?hl=en)
- [Midnight Lizard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/midnight-lizard/pbnndmlekkboofhnbonilimejonapojg)

Comment: Thank you a lot!